# Confusing with Regex? How to read Regex

Tags: java, regex

Consider that I'm working on Java programming language

**Note that this regex is trying to determine whether the input is Ipv6 format or not.**

There is a regex:

```
String regex = "^([a-fA-F0-9]{0,4}[:]){4,7}([a-fA-F0-9]{0,4})$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(input);
```

I am confused with `^` this character.

1. Is it covers `([a-fA-F0-9]{0,4}[:])` this one?
2. Or all statements `^([a-fA-F0-9]{0,4}[:]){4,7}([a-fA-F0-9]{0,4})$`?
3. And what is the purpose of this character?
4. Is this regex restricting each String (seperated by (semicolon): ) can length max 4 or not?

Basically, how to read this regex?

Comment: @jonrsharpe this regex is trying to determine whether the input is Ipv6 format or not.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the duplicate goes through regex syntax in general. A Q&A for every possible regex wouldn't scale very well!

Comment: See explanation: https://regex101.com/r/FYnZqS/1